# What does a constructor function's __proto__ attribute point to?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to go back and get a better understanding of prototypal inheritance. I understand that an instance's `__proto__` attribute points to the constructor function's `prototype` object, but what does the constructor function's `__proto__` attribute point to?

I had assumed that as the constructor function was itself an instance of Function, that it would point to the Function constructor's `prototype` object, but the following shows it to be an empty function.

```
var Example = function(){
   this.attribute = 'example';
}

var exampleInstance = new Example();

exampleInstance.__proto__ === Example.prototype // true
Example.__proto__ // function() {}
```

[Edit] Ovidiu Dolha has now confirmed my understanding so maybe this will be helpful to somebody.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Example.__proto__` will be the same as `Function.prototype`, just as `exampleInstance.__proto__` is the same as `Example.prototype`

This is because `Example` is an instance of a Function.

Everything will eventually get to `Object.prototype` which is the root in terms of prototypical inheritance.

Note that you should avoid using `__proto__` if possible as it is considered deprecated. Instead use `Object.getPrototypeOf()`

Comment: Thanks. So my assumption was correct and the fact that `Example.__proto__` returned an empty function is a quirk of the console.

Comment: Well I actually think `Function.prototype` is empty in the sense that it doesn't do anything when invoked - if I look at it using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Function.prototype)` then I can see it has some attributes/methods. The prototype is used like this (i.e. it's a holder of data and methods that e.g. the constructor defines - in this case Function)

Comment: But surely it should be an object, not a function. You don't invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a prototypal chain which goes till the end it finds the "Object" as the root.

The ECMAScript 5.1 specification states it like this:

In 15.3.4 Properties of the Function Prototype Object:

```
The value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of the Function prototype object is the standard built-in Object prototype object
```

And in 15.2.4 Properties of the Object Prototype Object

```
The value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of the Object prototype object is null
```

try this in your console.

```
console.log(exampleInstance);

Example
attribute
:
"example"
__proto__
:
Object
constructor
:
()
__proto__
:
Object
__defineGetter__
:
__defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__
:
__defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__
:
__lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__
:
__lookupSetter__()
constructor
:
Object()
hasOwnProperty
:
hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf
:
isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable
:
propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString
:
toLocaleString()
toString
:
toString()
valueOf
:
valueOf()
get __proto__
:
__proto__()
set __proto__
:
__proto__()
```